# How do you put divs or spans in the middle of table rows?

Tags: html, html-table

Every time I render the HTML the divs are pushed out of the table.

What is the proper way to get the same behavior as divs? I am trying to hide chunks of a table using jQuery.

Comment: Forget focus on the html div element for a moment.  What are you trying to achieve?  If what you are using isn't working for you, chances are it's the wrong tool (element).

Comment: What do you mean in the middle of rows? Can you show us code?

Comment: Have you considered using two tables with divs between it?

Answer (score 0):

**Follow This Format:**

```
<table width="200" border="1">
<tr id="1">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
<DIV>EXPANDING UPON ROW 2 AT BLOCK LEVEL But UN-effecting ROW 1 AND 3</DIV>
<tr id="3">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```